# window is not defined server side rendering(react + express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

If the browser URL is requested, routing works normally.

By the way, location = ${path};
The part that says Component An error occurs when calling react renderToString function.

I'm looking at web pack settings or something, but I can't find the cause. Help!

```
// App.js

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import moment from "moment";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import Footer from "./components/footer/Footer";

export default function App() {

    const [time, setTime] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('use effect..');
        setTime(moment().format('hh:mm:ss a'));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{height:'100%'}}>
            <Header/>
            <div style={{height:'100%'}}>
                <h1>Sample App</h1>
                <p>Current time is {time}</p>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )

}

// Header.js

import React from 'react';

export default function Header() {

    function goPage(path) {
        console.log(`goPage..`);
        console.log(window.location); // error
        // window.location = path;
    }

    return (
        <header style={{width: '100%', border: '1px dotted black'}}>
            <div>
                <span style={{padding: '4px'}}>My App |</span>
                <span style={{padding: '4px', cursor: 'pointer'}}>Home</span>
                <span style={{padding: '4px', cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={goPage('/about')}>About</span>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}
```

```
server.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const config = require('../webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);

import Router from '../routes/index';

import App from '../src/App';
import Html from "../src/Html";

const expressApp = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
    expressApp.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        publicPath: '/'
    }));
}
expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

expressApp.get('*', (request, response) => {

    console.log('request.. in express');
    console.log(Router.match(request));
    const component = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Router.match(request));

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Html
        title="Sample Title"
        description="Isomorphic web application sample"
        body={component}
    />);

    response.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>` + html);

});


expressApp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});


// Router

import React from 'react';

import App from "../src/App";
import NotFound from "../src/components/error/NotFound";
import Error from "../src/components/error/Error";
import About from "../src/components/about/About";

const routes = [
    {name : 'home', path : '/', action : () => <App/>},
    {name : 'about', path : '/about', action : () => <About/>},
    {name : '404', path : '/404', action : () => <NotFound/>},
    {name : '500', path : '/500', action : () => <Error/>},
];


export default {
    match(location) {
        console.log(location.path);
        const route = routes.find(x => x.path === location.path);

        if (route) {
            try {
                return route.action();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('err');
                return routes.find(x => x.path === '/500').action();
            }
        } else {
            console.log('404');
            return routes.find(x => x.path === '/404').action();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// webpack config

const path = require('path');

// plugin
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');


// SSR
const ssr = {
    mode : 'development',
    entry: './server/server.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        filename: "server.js",
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: false,
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(.js|.jsx)/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: [
                    path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
                    path.join(__dirname, '/routes/index.js'),
                    path.join(__dirname, '/server/server.js'),
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['build']
        })
    ],
};

// CSR
const csr = {
    mode : 'development',
    entry:'./client/client.js',
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        filename: 'client.js'
    },
    target: 'web',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(.js|.jsx)/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: [
                    path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
                    path.join(__dirname, '/routes/index.js'),
                    path.join(__dirname, '/client/client.js'),
                ],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    // devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new MomentLocalesPlugin({
            localesToKeep: ['es-us', 'ru'],
        }),
    ]
};


module.exports = [ssr, csr];
```

The server is composed of express, and is set to babel7 and webpack4.
If you look at the server.js part, you get the corresponding react component in the request URL.
If renderToString() is called on the obtained component, an error of window is not defined occurs.
I really want to solve it. Please help.

Comment: If you want to run the entire code and run it, leave a repository address.

https://github.com/katanazero86/isomorphic-web

Answer (score 0):

Why `window` is not defined in SSR

On the ssr there is no definition for window. Because window is a browser based property.

you need to do something to  avoid that. e.g

```
function goPage(path) {
        console.log(`goPage..`);
        if (window) {
           console.log(window.location);
        }
    }
```

and on the server side you can get the url by this

```
req.url
// or
app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params)
}
```